# Are overflow errors okay in release mode?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm building a Flutter app that targets Web and Desktop platforms, with a resizable window. The window can be made extremely small, to the point where there isn't room to show any meaningful UI elements, and overflow errors occur.

Is it okay to let this happen in release mode, or should I be preventing these somehow by hiding all UI elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is better to avoid any error in release ,
UI overflow will not cause  your app to crash however it will show the overflowed spots grey not stripped yellow black like in debug mode.

so the answer **try not to have any overflow** unless its impossible to fit it and the size is extremely small , then you **hide it**.

Comment: Yes, I'm totally agree with you